# Asp.net mvc does not send email in godaddy hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I have a asp.net mvc site hosted in godaddy, but email sending is not working. In server code I writed the following

```
var emailmessage = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage()
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            From = from,
            To = to,
            BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html,
            Priority = MailPriority.High
        };


        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
        SmtpMail.Send(emailmessage);
```

In web config I added the code

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
   <smtp from="admin@flex.am">
    <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"/>
   </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

What can I do else?
Thanks!

Comment: SMTP port and password are missing.

Comment: Are they required? According to the godaddy articles I can use "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" without any port and passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below snippet works for me. try this code and if it don't work for you, can you log whole exception message.

```
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
// Sender e-mail address.
Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
// Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To.Add("admin@abc.com");
//Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
Msg.Body ="some body message";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
smtp.Send(Msg);
```

Comment: Have you added settings in web.config or this code is enough?

Comment: No, this code won't require smtp setting in web.config as all these were hard coded in the code itself. Not a best practise though!!

Comment: The only difference  is that you are using SmtpClient class but I use   SmtpMail.SmtpServer. Maybe it causes the problem?

Comment: Not sure. but SmptMail is deprecated - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Man you saved my time! Perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var senderEmail = new MailAddress("Your email", "Your Name");
var receiverEmail = new MailAddress("Receiver email", "Receiver name");
var password = "your password"; //I used here APP password 

var subject = "Subject";
var body = @"<html><body><p>Dear XYZ,</p></body></html>";
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net",
    Port = 25,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderEmail.Address, password)
})
using (var message = new MailMessage(senderEmail, receiverEmail)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true
})
client.Send(message);
```